# How to insert into in ARC2

Tags: insert, sparql, arc2

I am trying to insert an individual into in ARC 2, without any success for now...
I used `INSERT INTO ...CONSTRUCT`

```php
 $query = 'PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 PREFIX untitled-ontology-120:
 <http://www.semanticweb.org/usuario/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-120>
 INSERT INTO <http://localhost:80/proyecto1/data/mp2.rdf> CONSTRUCT
 {?c rdf:label untitled-ontology-120:Pamplona.}
     WHERE{?c rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual.
}';
```

Tee errors I receive is

```
 " executed INSERT, returned:  int(0) Query errorsArray ( [0] => Could not properly handle "PREFIX owl:
```

When I tried to do it without `CONSTRUCT`

```php
$query = 'PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
 PREFIX untitled-ontology-120:
 <http://www.semanticweb.org/usuario/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-ontology-120>
 INSERT INTO <http://localhost:80/proyecto1/data/mp2.rdf> 
 {untitled-ontology-120:Pamplona rdf:type owl:NamedIndividual.
 }';
```

And I received the response:

```
executed INSERT, returned: 
array(3) { ["query_type"]=> string(6) "insert" ["result"]=> array(2) 
{ ["t_count"]=> int(1) ["load_time"]=> float(0.0396) } 
["query_time"]=> float(0.047343969345093) }
```

This response seems to me as if smth has been done, but...  there is no anything added to the RDF file with the ontology

Could anybody help me?
**AKSW**!!!! S.O.S.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but at least you should use the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-update/#insertData)  and not building some query that doesn't conform to any syntax. form where do you have `INSERT INTO ... CONSTRUCT ... WHERE ...`? This is SPARQL and not SQL, thus, there is no `INSERT INTO`

Comment: The problem is that ARC2 do not support SPARQL 1.1 Update, but SPARQL +.   
And on the page of ARC2 they give some example which is like this

Comment: INSERT INTO <http://example.com/> {
      <#foo> <bar> "baz" . 
     }
That is why I tried this construction...

Comment: Ok, so maybe the parser doesn't consider PREFIX declarations in the beginning and you have to use full URIs? Does this work then?

Comment: I tried 
     ' $query = '
      INSERT INTO <http://localhost:80/proyecto1/data/mp2.rdf> 
      {<http://www.semanticweb.org/usuario/ontologies/2017/2/untitled-
      ontology-120#Pamplona> <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-
      schema#type> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#NamedIndividual>.
      }';
......
echo $query;
.....

 /* execute the query */
$res = $store->query($query);

echo var_dump($store->getErrors()). "ERRORES   <br>";
echo "executed INSERT, returned: ". "<br>";
echo var_dump($res); '

Comment: and   the output I received was 

'INSERT INTO { . }array(0) { } ERRORES '

'executed INSERT, returned: '

'array(3) { ["query_type"]=> string(6) "insert" ["result"]=> array(2) { ["t_count"]=> int(1) ["load_time"]=> float(0.1856) } ["query_time"]=> float(0.19382500648499) }'

It does not see the query text, as it seems....maybe is the question of ' " <> etc... symbols

Comment: I mean 

echo $query;  is INSERT INTO { . } with an empty string inside the {}

Comment: Why do you always omit the protocol `http` in the URIs?

Comment: I don´t know. I use prefix... to simplify the sintaxis. I will try now with http´s!!!

Comment: The same resullt. The rdf file do not change

Comment: I guess there are some other library for PHP which do work better that ARC?